# Modeling dielectric constant as a function of temperature to obtain Curie Temperature in ferroelectric material

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, dielectric

I am performing an experiment to measure the Curie Temperature ($T_C$) of $BaTiO_3$ by measuring the capacitance changes in the sample on changing temperatures. Based on the module, and what I have looked up so far the data is supposed to look something like this:

[image]

The heating and cooling are just data-taking labels - one run was by heating the capacitor all the way and then taking data as it cooled; the second was the other way round.

Now, by inspection the Curie Temperature is when the $\epsilon_r$ reaches the peak which is roughly 131-132 degrees. This agrees with what is expected of us as far as I understand.

On a very surface level I have understood that the $\epsilon_r$ in $T < T_C$ has a different form than for $T > T_C$.

At least for magnetic analogue of this, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature#Approaching_Curie_temperature_from_above) gives this description for $T > T_C$:

$$ \chi \approx \frac{C}{(T - T_C)^{\gamma}}  $$

and for $T < T_C$

$$ M \approx (T-T_C)^\beta$$

These, or at least the forms of these make sense to me to use in describing $\epsilon_r$ in both $T < T_C$ and $T > T_C$.

**Questions**

**First**, of all is this line of thinking reasonable at all? If not, what is a better way to model $\epsilon_r$ as a function of $T$.

**Second**, if what I am thinking is a reasonable approach, then I would like to know how to combine the $T < T_C$ and $T>T_C$ descriptions like those used in the magnetic case. Naively, I think to make a model like so:

$$ \epsilon_r = A (T_C - T)^\beta + \frac{B}{(T- T_C)^\gamma}$$

and fit my data using curve_fit of python.scipy to obtain $A, B, T_C, \beta, \gamma$.

However, if I think to do that and since $\beta < 1$ (from Wikipedia), the first term will break my model for $T > T_C$.

Of course I could place a condition to apply different descriptions for the two different domains, i.e for $T < T_C$ fit the first term, and for $T > T_C$ fit the second term. But doing that would require that I know what $T_C$ is, and what I am trying to do here is to obtain $T_C$ itself just from the data.

I'd appreciate any help in terms of references or articles that can help me in this.

Comment: On purely mathematical viewpoint a model equation without condition would involve special functions such as Heaviside or others. In some cases the regression can lead to the value of the "braking" point ($T_c$) together with the approximates of the other parameters. For example in much simpler cases see https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf . Of course your problem is more arduous. In order to check if a solution is possible with the special method proposed I need a example of your data (numerical, not too big, representative of the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On a very surface level I have understood that the $_{r}$ in  < $_{}$ has a different form than for  > $_{}$.

Correct, it is often written as:

$$ \frac{1}{ \varepsilon } = \begin{cases}  -2 \big( \frac{T - T_{C}}{C} \big) & T < T_{C}\\ \\ \big( \frac{T - T_{C}}{C} \big) & T > T_{C}\end{cases} $$

The result from Landau Ginsburg Devonshire theory leads to this inherently piecewise solution, so attempting to define $\varepsilon$ as a single function is not viable.

> Of course I could place a condition to apply different descriptions for the two different domains, i.e for $ < _{}$ fit the first term, and for $ > _{}$ fit the second term. But doing that would require that I know what $_{C}$ is, and what I am trying to do here is to obtain $_{}$ itself just from the data.

Typically $_{}$ is found just that way; either by looking for the temperature of maximum $\varepsilon$, or finding where the slope is 0 by numerically taking the derivative of your data.  Alternatively, you could take the inverse of all of your data, and fit the $T > _{}$ and $T < _{}$ to lines, and confirm that the slopes of the lines differ by a factor of -2 (or -1/2).

You can find both $T_{C}$ and $C$ by fitting.  With the amount of data that you have, and the aforementioned fitting function, you can get both of those numbers.

Depending on what tool you are use, fitting data to a piecewise function is not problematic.  Origin, Mathematica, MatLab, and other similar programs have built in capabilities to fit data to a function of your choosing.

For barium titanate in particular, you need to be more careful, because it has ***3*** Curie temperatures, with the one you found at 131-132 C being the highest one.  To truly accurately calculate relative permittivity you need to account for the 2 other phase transitions that occur at lower temperatures.

[image: Relative permittivity vs temperature for barium titanate]

Therefore, to truly accurately model this system you need to have a piecewise function with ***4*** conditions to account for each of the 3 phase transitions.  For what you are doing, it might be sufficient to just consider the one Curie temperature, but that really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.